# What CUDA shared memory size means

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to solve this problem myself but I can't.
So I want to get yours advice.

I am writing kernel code like this. VGA is GTX 580.

```
xxxx <<< blockNum, threadNum, SharedSize >>> (... threadNum ...)
(note. SharedSize is set 2*threadNum)

__global__ void xxxx(..., int threadNum, ...)
{
    extern __shared__ int shared[];
    int* sub_arr = &shared[0];
    int* sub_numCounting = &shared[threadNum];
    ...
}
```

My program creates about 1085 blocks and 1024 threads per block (I am trying to handle a huge array).

So the size of shared memory per block is 8192 (`1024*2*4`) bytes, right?

I figured out that I can use maximum 49152 bytes in shared memory per block on GTX 580 by using `cudaDeviceProp`.

And I know that the GTX 580 has 16 processors, thread block can be implemented on processor.

But my program returns an error (8192 bytes < 49152 bytes).

I used `printf` in the kernel to see whether it operates well or not but several blocks do not operate: Even though I create 1085 blocks, actually only 50~100 blocks operate.

And I want to know whether blocks which operate on the same processor share the same shared memory address or not. If not, do they allocate other memory for shared memory?

I can't quite understand what maximum size of shared memory per block means.

Give me advice.

Comment: Hopefully the shared memory size is 2*threadNum*sizeof(int), otherwise your problem isn't asking for too much shared memory, it is too little.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, blocks on the same multiprocessor shared the same amount of shared memory, which is 48KB per multiprocessor for your GPU card (compute capability 2.0). So if you have N blocks on the same multiprocessor, the maximum size of shared memory per block is (48/N) KB.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the answer that I want. And I have one more question. (I'm sorry...) Is it possible reuse the shared memory space? I mean thread blocks which will be executed on processor can use shared memory spaces that was being used by previous thread blocks which completed their job. (I'm sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Although a single multiprocessor have N blocks in kernel code, I think actually N blocks doesn't operate at once. So I think there is order in multiprocessor selecting thread block which is first and which is next.

Comment: @Umbrella You are right, not all blocks are processed simultaneously if you have more blocks than multiprocessors. And shared memory has a lifetime of the block, so when the block is done, shared memory is released and of course can be re-used by up-coming blocks. See [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/208801731) for more info.

Comment: I'm impressed with your very kind reply. Very very thank you.

Comment: Does the calculation multiprocessor-blocks really work this way? After reading https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999749/find-the-limit-of-shared-memory-that-can-be-used-per-block/ and making some tests the direction seems to be the opposite -- shared memory size used dictates how many blocks per processor are used.